# convert Date from "/Date(xxxxxxxxxxxx)/" to datetime in c#

Tags: c#, datetime

I am getting date from javascript to c# in this format "`/Date(1330540200000)/`"

I want to convert this "`/Date(1330540200000)/`" format to `MM:dd:yyyy` format in c#.

I am able to convert it in javascript but here I want to convert this in c#.

Comment: What does this number represent?

Comment: Personally, I try to avoid the default serialized value, and would advice you to format your dates before returning them to the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this:

```
public static string ParseFromString(string dateTime){
    return new DateTime(1970,1,1).AddMilliseconds(double.Parse(Regex.Match ("/Date(1330540200000)/", @"(\d+)").Value)).ToString("MM:dd:yyyy");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a lot of javascript components that sends a a `timestamp` information as date. You can use a function like this:

```
public static DateTime ConvertTimeStampToDateTime(double value)
{
    DateTime origin = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0); //Unix Epoch on January 1st, 1970

    return origin.AddMilliseconds(value);
}
```

After you've got the `DateTime` structure, you could use `ToString(string format)` to format as you want into a string, for sample:

```
// a string timeStamp (for sample, in string).
string timeStampString = "1330540200000";

// pass as a double, convert it if it is a string.
DateTime myDate = ConvertTimeStampToDateTime(double.Parse(timeStampString)); 

string myDateFormated = myDate.ToString("MM:dd:yyyy");
```

Comment: How do I take number out from that string ?

Comment: You can use `double.Parse` function. Look my edits :)

Comment: Problem is that when I convert it to string , It comes as "/Date(1330540200000)/" & not as "1330540200000"

Comment: @vaibhavshah: String.Split is your friend. Something like that should work: `string extracted = fullTimeStampString.Split('(')[1].Split(')')[0]`.